# Form going to DELETE route instead of POST route

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my application I have a `Film` model, and a `Log` model (which is a join table between `Film` and `User`. I also have a `Like` model where a user can like a film (as well as reviews, comments, etc). This `Like` model is not related to the `Log` model.

For some reason, if a film has already been liked by the user, whenever they try to create a log, the form will take them to the DELETE /logs route even tough there is no delete method specified in the form. Oddly, when a film hasn't been liked, the form works correctly. Why?!

I'm currently running Rails 7, with Hotwire. Here's some of the files:

**logs/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= render "shared/modal" do %>
  <%= form_with(model: log) do |form| %>
    <div class="flex">
      <div class="mr-4 hidden sm:block">
        <%= render FilmCoverComponent.new(film, size: :lg, link: false) %>
      </div>
      <div class="flex-1 flex flex-col justify-between space-y-2">
        <div class="text-display text-xl"><%= film.name %></div>
        <%= form.hidden_field :film_id, value: film.id %>
        <div class="flex">
          <%= form.submit "Save", class: "btn-base btn-primary btn-md btn-block" %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Which displays the following html (this example from when a film has been already liked):

```
<turbo-frame id="modal-body">
            
  <form action="/logs" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="7KYjpeYFRWNuH5g2aOrLVTwXQfU0FUAN2vW49kjK1xLcwYJCIxU-G7W6-JSrnRDFU2jOnqyJMPnD9NmCg3Tetw" autocomplete="off">
    <div class="flex">
      <div class="mr-4 hidden sm:block">
        <div class="group relative">
  <div class="flex items-center justify-center rounded-lg w-48 text-lg aspect-[3/4] border border-slate-700 bg-slate-800 font-semibold text-slate-400 text-center overflow-hidden">Film Five</div>
    <div class="hidden group-hover:flex absolute inset-x-0 bottom-0 w-min mb-1 mx-auto items-center bg-black/50 py-1 px-2 rounded space-x-2">
      <a data-turbo-frame="modal" href="/logs/new?film_id=5"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 488.348 488.348" fill="currentColor" class="w-5 h-5 ">
    <path d="...."></path>
</svg>
</a>
      
  <div id="film_5_likes" class="flex">
      <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete" autocomplete="off"><button class="inline-flex items-baseline rounded-lg" type="submit">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" class="w-5 h-5 text-red-500 hover:text-red-700">
<path d="...." fill="currentColor"></path>
</svg>

        
</button><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="x0ifxiJjxF4DnFt4v3x1cpDi1ZcfCg2HDWS7Q0i38Rmr3uU5W8JZzS9lLvEVnP46YWNiTwMCLrY-6BeJDHYqxQ" autocomplete="off"></div>

      <div class="relative" data-controller="dropdown" data-dropdown-active-target="#navbar_menu" data-dropdown-enter-timeout="75" data-dropdown-entering-class="ease-out duration-75" data-dropdown-invisible-class="opacity-0 scale-95" data-dropdown-leave-timeout="75" data-dropdown-leaving-class="ease-in duration-75" data-dropdown-visible-class="opacity-100 scale-100" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <div data-action="click->dropdown#toggle click@window->dropdown#hide" role="button" data-dropdown-target="button" tabindex="0">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="none" class="w-5 h-5 hover:text-primary-300">
<path d="...." fill="currentColor"></path>
<path d="...." fill="currentColor"></path>
<path d="...." fill="currentColor"></path>
</svg>

        </div>
        <div data-dropdown-target="menu" class="hidden absolute left-0 z-10 mt-2 w-40 origin-top-left rounded-md bg-slate-700 py-1 ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 focus:outline-none divide-y divide-slate-500 opacity-0 scale-95" role="menu" tabindex="-1">
          <div>
            <a data-action="click->dropdown#toggle" data-turbo-frame="modal" class="block px-4 py-2 text-xs text-slate-200 hover:text-primary-100 hover:bg-slate-600" href="/logs/new?film_id=5">Log or review</a>
              <a data-action="click->dropdown#toggle" data-turbo-method="put" class="block px-4 py-2 text-xs text-slate-200 hover:text-primary-100 hover:bg-slate-600" href="/username1/backlog?film=film-five">Add to backlog</a>
            <a data-action="click->dropdown#toggle" class="block px-4 py-2 text-xs text-slate-200 hover:text-primary-100 hover:bg-slate-600" href="/films/film-five">Go to film</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

      </div>
      <div class="flex-1 flex flex-col justify-between space-y-2">
        <div class="text-display text-xl">Film Five</div>
        <input value="5" autocomplete="off" type="hidden" name="log[film_id]" id="log_film_id">
        <div class="flex">
          <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Save" class="btn-base btn-primary btn-md btn-block" data-disable-with="Save">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div></form>

</turbo-frame>
```

Comment: `<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete" autocomplete="off">` is the cultprit here - this overrides the HTTP method in Rack. There isn't enough information here so that we can figure out why its being rendered but my guess is that the view component is doing something screwy like outputting a form which isn't permitted in HTML.

Comment: can't have forms within forms ^. `button_to` makes a form. my guess is 'unlike' button with `method: :delete`.

Comment: @Alex to expand on that; since nested forms are not permitted in HTML the actual behavior is not standardized. If you for example do `button_to ..., method: :delete` the form submit event will often bubble up to the outer form and submit it instead with all the inputs from the "inner" form included. The solution is to use `link_to ..., data: { turbo_method: :delete }` which doesn't create a form.